# Enlarge neq symbol

Tags: symbols

I resize the not equal symbol, but it doesn't work. What is the problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\let\oldneq\neq
\DeclareRobustCommand{\neq}{%%%%
\mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@notequal\relation}%%%%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@notequal}[2]{%%%%
\raisebox{-0.1\height}{\scalebox{4.35}{\hspace{-0.1mm}$\m@th#1\oldneq$}}%%%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[\neq\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Again? You've been asking the same question over and over again, without ever tellig what's the purpose of such magnification.

Comment: you could use `\NewCommandCopy` instead of `\let`  but what is the use case here why can't you simply use a larger font?

Comment: The problem is that `\neq` is already robust, so yo can't use simply `\let`. Either you do as David suggests or you use `\expandafter\let\expandafter\oldneq\csname neq \endcsname`.

Comment: I am using a different font and the symbols are very small there. When I enlarge all of them, the document is corrupted. So I have to enlarge one by one. Thank you for your helps. I did what you said and it worked.